# "Failed to instantiate module ngSanitize" when pre-rendering AngualrJS site with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs

I'm attempting to pre-render my AngularJS site using PhantomJS. (With phantomjs-runner.js from http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html) I'm unable to load the page through PhantomJS as the error below occurs. This error does not occur in IE/Chrome/Firefox.

How do I go about fixing this error?

**Error:**

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module SpaceForAfrica due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module dialogs due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngSanitize due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngSanitize' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a
module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$injector/nomod?p0=ngSanitize
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.js:1507
    at ensure (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.js:1435)
    at module (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.js:1717)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.js:3527
```

**Module config**

```
var SpaceForAfrica = angular.module('SpaceForAfrica', ['ngRoute', 'HashBangURLs', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls', 'google-maps', 'ui.growl', 'dialogs', 'ngSanitize', 'angularSpinner','angulartics', 'angulartics.google.analytics']).config(spaceForAfricaConfig);
```

Answer (score 18):

It looks like you might be missing a reference to the ngSanitize code.  ngSanitize is part of the AngularJS framework (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize), however, you have to include a separate  reference **before your PhantomJS reference** in order to utilize it.

It appears you are using version 1.2.1 of AngularJS, so you could easily just add one of these tags (or grab the code to include in your own app.)

Non-minified:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Minified:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```